# change color of bottom in ngfor from array

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

i create a dinamic ionic card and i would change color in each of this but i don't know how i can do that. i have an array like this

```
+-------------------------------+
|DESART|COLORWEB|...............|
+------+--------+---------------+
|bla123|#057EEF |...............|
+------+--------+---------------+
|bla232|#F3FF05 |...............|
+------+--------+---------------+
|bla151|#05gg00 |...............|
+------+--------+---------------+
|bla276|#F30005 |...............|
+------+--------+---------------+
```

and this is my c

```
  <ion-card class="coworker-card" *ngFor="let itemDotaz of this.MyApp.json_articoli">
    <ion-card-header >
      <ion-card-title>
        <ion-button /*here i must change color*/>
          <ion-icon name="brush-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        {{this.MyApp.DoData(itemDotaz.DESART)}}          {{this.MyApp.DoData(itemDotaz.COLORWEB)}}
      </ion-card-title>
      
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>
        sono preseni {{itemDotaz.QTAART}} articoli di tipo {{this.MyApp.DoData(itemDotaz.CODART)}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>


</ion-content>
```

Comment: Do you want a different color for each row or only for the last row?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Could you rephrase it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngStyle` to achieve that like this:

```
  <ion-button [ngStyle]="{'color': itemDotaz.COLORWEB}">
    <ion-icon name="brush-outline"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
```